# How do I install Australis (Firefox nightly) on 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox

I've seen opinions on Australis here: [Anyone try Australis yet? (New Firefox UI)](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/anyone-try-australis-yet-new-firefox-ui/1220).

How can I install it on **64-bit** Ubuntu? Is there a ppa? [“Ubuntu Mozilla Daily Build Team” team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/firefox-aurora) has builds for Aurora (currently Firefox 27) but I couldn't find a ppa for Firefox 28 nightly builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some info about **Australis** and how to start using it under **Ubuntu** via **PPA** can be found here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/11/australis-ui-lands-in-firefox-nightly.html

Apparently, all you need is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox-trunk
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. Nightly shows v28.01a (2013-11-17), but still no Australis. It only works for Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10 apparently.

Comment: For Firefox 12.x build from: http://nightly.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that PPA is not regularly updated. Is is currently about twenty days old. If you install the current build it will update daily.

Current build location: https://nightly.mozilla.org/

Instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion/MozillaBuilds